# How to alias name for IP Address

Tags: centos, redhat, bind, centos5, httpd.conf

I have a website which is hosted in local Server (CentOS 5.x) (Hostname: xxx.yyy.local, IP : 192.168.5.25). I can browse the site typing server ip in the browser from my Local Network.

How can I get an alias for “http://192.168.5.25/support” Eg: http://mycompanysupport ?

Note this is required for Internal network only. I don't want to access this site outside of my network.

Comment: You talk to whoever is handling the internal DNS for your company network.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple sites (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211533/alias-name-for-ip-address)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [it has been also posted on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211533/alias-name-for-ip-address). [Don't do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 1):

Edit the hosts file of your local machine (or the server running your DNS) to include the following:

```
192.168.5.25     mycompanysupport
```

The location of your hosts file will vary depending upon your platform.

For Windows NT and Windows 2000:

```
C:\winnt\system32\drivers\etc
```

For Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 or Windows 8:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

For *nix:

```
/etc/hosts
```

The hosts file must be edited as the Administrator or root user. In Windows, remember to open your text editor as the Administrator user. In *nix, open the file for editing as the root user.

Comment: I don't want to edit /etc/hosts in all the clients. What entry do I need to add in my local DNS? I am using BIND.

Comment: You don't need to edit the `/etc/hosts` in all clients. Edit the `/etc/hosts` file on the server running your DNS daemon.

Comment: I have edited /etc/hosts file on the Server running my DNS daemon. But still I am not able to access the site with the link. I have pointed my Laptop DNS to my internal DNS server IP.